# Text Effect creates Transparent Background

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to figure out how to use the text effect.  Basically, all I'm doing is selecting a clip and then adding an effect.  When doing this, there is transform and a handful of other ones.  But then, if I select the new effect strip, and then select change effect, I get around 15 effects showing up, one of which is text.  I wonder why these don't show up the first time, but never mind.  As soon as the text effect is applied, I see the text itself ... on top of a transparent background.  I can't find any control or way to change this or understand why it would cover up the video that it supposed to be keying over.

Thanks for any help ...
Steve

Comment: Please show your work in a well chosen collection of Blender screen captures.   Please see multiple tutorials on the Blender area in question.  That maybe VSE Video Sequence Editor.  The famous video website that rhymes with noonube has tutorials.  Perhaps you need a video tag to your question.  I find the your statement difficult to understand and encourage you to write a new statement after seeing tutorials. Perhaps other people find your statement quite easy to read.

Comment: VSE. Often if you simply [replace] a layer layer on top of other layers you will not see the other layers, which you today will consider to be a mistake. You may need to [alpha blend] the top layer. Know the difference between [replace] and [alpha blend] as an attribute of the strip in VSE.